# Why I have StackOverFlow when i try convert my DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

When I try to fetch my tasks I have StackOverflowError that is bellow. I think that this error because of my mapper, do u know how can I change my mapper for work next code?
This is my Task Entity class:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = SELECT_TASKS,
                query = "SELECT * from tasks",
                resultClass = Task.class),
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = DELETE_REJECTED_TASKS,
                query = "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE status = 0 AND CURRENT_DATE - :" + PARAMETER_DURATION + " > creation_date",
                resultClass = Task.class),
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = FIND_REJECTED_TASKS,
                query = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 0 AND CURRENT_DATE - :" + PARAMETER_DURATION + " > creation_date",
                resultClass = Task.class),
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = SELECT_TASKS_BY_ASSIGNED_USER_ID,
                query = "select * from tasks inner join users u on tasks.user_id = u.id where user_id = :" + PARAMETER_USER_ID,
                resultClass = Task.class)
})
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "priority")
    private Priority priority;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @PrePersist
    private void setUp() {
        this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.status = Status.TODO;
    }
}
```

I have this User Entity

```
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{

    public static final String SELECT_USERS = "selectUsers";
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "statistic_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserStatistic userStatistic;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JsonManagedReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And this DTO

```
package ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.*;
import ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.domain.User;
import ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.enums.Priority;
import ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.enums.Status;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

/**
 * Class that provide DTO pattern
 *
 * @author Zhytariuk Oleksandr
 */
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
public class TaskDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private Priority priority;
    private Status status;

    private UserDTO userDTO;
}
```

this task mapper

```
package ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.domain.Task;
import ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.dto.TaskDTO;

/**
 * Class that provide methods for converting {@link Task} to {@link TaskDTO}
 *
 * @author Zhytariuk Oleksandr
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))
public class TaskMapper {

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    /**
     * Convert task to taskDTO
     *
     * @param task param that need to convert
     * @return taskDTO
     */
    public TaskDTO convertToTaskDTO(Task task) {

        return TaskDTO.builder()
                .id(task.getId())
                .creationDate(task.getCreationDate())
                .description(task.getDescription())
                .name(task.getName())
                .status(task.getStatus())
                .priority(task.getPriority())
                .userDTO(userMapper.convertToUserDTO(task.getUser()))
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Convert taskDTO to task
     *
     * @param taskDTO param that need to convert
     * @return task
     */
    public Task convertTaskDTOtoTask(TaskDTO taskDTO) {

        return Task.builder()
                .id(taskDTO.getId())
                .creationDate(taskDTO.getCreationDate())
                .description(taskDTO.getDescription())
                .name(taskDTO.getName())
                .status(taskDTO.getStatus())
                .user(userMapper.convertUserDTOtoUser(taskDTO.getUserDTO()))
                .priority(taskDTO.getPriority())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Ok for fetch task i have next method in my controller:

```
    @GetMapping("{taskId}")
    public ResponseEntity<TaskDTO> fetchTask(@PathVariable Long taskId) throws TaskDAOException {
        log.info("FetchTask.E with Task id: {}", taskId);
        final Task task = taskService.findById(taskId);
        if (Objects.isNull(task)) {
            throw new TaskNotFoundException("Task with id " + taskId + " was not found");
        }
        final TaskDTO taskDTO = taskMapper.convertToTaskDTO(task);
        log.info("FetchTask.X with TaskDTO: {}", taskDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(taskDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I try to fetch my Task that have User I have next Error. What I should to do for resolve it

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6858996.convertToTaskDTO(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper.convertToUserDTO(UserMapper.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7183b9d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79812a8.convertToUserDTO(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper.convertToTaskDTO(TaskMapper.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8203d1d7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6858996.convertToTaskDTO(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper.convertToUserDTO(UserMapper.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7183b9d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.UserMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79812a8.convertToUserDTO(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper.convertToTaskDTO(TaskMapper.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8203d1d7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ua.zhytariuk.planningsystem.model.mapper.TaskMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6858996.convertToTaskDTO(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: It looks like - via several steps - the `convertToUserDTO` which you've shown being *called*, but which you haven't shown us the code for, calls into `convertToTaskDTO`, which in turn calls `convertToUserDTO`, etc. That's the chain to work on - do the two really need to refer to each other, and how do you expect them to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet What DTO i should have for work this code? I need to replace List<TaskDTO> tasks?

Comment: I didn't suggest replacing any DTOs. I'm suggesting you look at your `convertToUserDTO` and `convertToTaskDTO` methods, because it looks like they're calling each other recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a User `u1` has a task `t1` which refers to `u1` again, directly or indirectly. To solve this, the DTO model usually is modeled in a non-cyclic way i.e. a task should refer to a `SimpleUserDTO` instead, which doesn't contain the task list.